# How to click on multiple imageview

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

Hello I'm new to android development. So I've tried this coding where when I clicked on the imageview it will change to another image. And it's working perfectly. But I have 10 imageview. And every time each of the image being click it will change to another image. Is there any simpler code to be use on 10 imageview? How can I do it? Thanks :)

```
package com.example.subtraction;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Level_1 extends Activity {
private ImageView imageOne=null;
private ImageView imageTwo=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_1);

    imageOne = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageTwo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newImage);

    imageOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick (View view)
        {
            imageTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    imageTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            imageOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single OnClickListener and put your 10 ImageView objects in an array. Something like this:

```
package com.example.subtraction;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Level_1 extends Activity {
    private ImageView[] images = new ImageView[2];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_1);

        images[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        images[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);

        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        }
    }

    private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                if (v != images[i]) {
                    images[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
}
```